# How do I print all the polled records from my Kafka cluster to a text file?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

After polling all the messages and trying to append them to a text file, the text file is still blank.

I tried PrintWriter's write and print functions too, didn't work.

Code:

```
PrintWriter recordsFile = new PrintWriter("./recordsFile.txt");

while (some condition) {
    kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100)).forEach(consumerRecord -> {
        recordsFile.append(consumerRecord + "\n");
        System.out.println(consumerRecord);
    });
}

recordsFile.flush();
recordsFile.close();
```

In the above code, records are being printed to the console, which means the polls were successful. Why is the file still blank then?

My guess is that the poll operation starts a separate thread, what do you think is the problem here?

Please note that I have taken care of FileNotFoundException possibility, subscribed to a topic, etc. I left out those details to focus on the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `recordsFile.println(consumerRecord.toString())`.

But, do you need to do this within another application? If not, you can do the same with Kafka Connect

Open `config/connect-file-sink.properties`, and change the topic and file name there.

Run `bin/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties`

Comment: recordsFile.println(consumerRecord.toString()) is not working either. Here I think the problem is, before appending the records to the file, the program moves on to the next iteration of polling. This is just a guess of course.